# Concatenating strings with RxJava2

Tags: rx-java2, rx-android

I have a simple List of my POJO called Sport which has a name field .
What is the best way to concat all the names in the List?

```
Observable.just(member.getSports())
          .map(sports -> {
              StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
              for (Sport sport : sports) {
                  builder.append(sport.getName());
              }
              return builder.toString()
           })
```

I believe there must be a better way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Willi Mentzel is right that you don't need Rx, but if you want to use it anyway in plain Java for readability, here's a cool way to leverage Rx2

```
// Get a list of sports names
Observable<String> names = Observable.fromIterable(member.getSports()).map(sport -> sport.getName())

// Concat list into a single string output separated by comma
Single<String> listOfNames = names.collect(StringBuilder::new, (sb, x) -> sb.append(x).append(", ")).map(StringBuilder::toString).toSingle()
```

One-liner in Java:

```
Observable.fromIterable(member.getSports()).map(sport -> sport.getName()).collect(StringBuilder::new, (sb, x) -> sb.append(x).append(", ")).map(StringBuilder::toString).toSingle()
```

One-liner in Kotlin with RxKotlin

```
member.getSports().map { it.name }.toObservable().collect(StringBuilder::new, (sb, x) -> sb.append(x).append(", ")).map(StringBuilder::toString).toSingle()
```

Produces:

> volleyball, hockey, racquetball

Comment: I would not recommend using RxKotlin for that. The standard library already provided you with joinToString. See here: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html

Comment: And just because it fits theoretically on one line doesn't make it a one liner :D

Answer (score 2):

You should always strive for code that is easy to read and therefore to maintain.

You don't need RxJava for that, just streams:

```
String joined = member.getSports().stream()
            .map(sport -> sport.getName())
            .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
```

**Edit 1:**

Since streams are not an option. I wouldn't use RxJava then anyways. Just use the code from inside your lambda.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (Sport sport : sports) {
   builder.append(sport.getName());
}
builder.toString()
```

**Edit 2:**
Or you build a more generalized version, in case you need a prefix and postfix as well:

```
// Inside Utils.java
public static <T> String joinToString(List<T> list, String separator, String prefix, String postfix, Function<T, String> func) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    builder.append(prefix);

    if (!list.isEmpty()) {
        for (T t : list.subList(0, list.size() - 1)) {
            builder.append(func.apply(t));
            builder.append(separator);
        }

        builder.append(list.get(list.size() - 1));
    }

    builder.append(postfix);
    return builder.toString();
}
```

and use it like this:

```
Utils.joinToString(member.getSports(), "", "", "", Sport::getName));
```

This comes pretty close to [Kotlin's joinToString](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html) extension function.

Comment: Unfortunately i cant use streams since i am on Android which doesnt support java 8 streams as yet

Comment: @MuhammadAhmedAbuTalib Can you use Kotlin :D?

Comment: Hehe I wish i could. Our deadlines are very brutal and we have absolutely no time for a complete shift to kotlin. Its in our todos though after deployment